# How would I go about making a search filter bar in my React Native App?

Tags: react-native

I have this function component called Map, where I have PDF names stored in an Object. I display those PDF names on my screen, but I want to create a search bar where I can search through the PDF names because there are quite a lot and filter my results based off that search. Is there a way I can do this? My code is shown below, where all the of pdf names are stored and displayed on the screen in {item}. So I basically want to search the text (pdf names) stored in that variable. Please help.

```
const Map = ({props}) => {
...
return (
      <View> 
        <List>
             {
               Object.keys(pdf).map((item)=>
                 { 
                   return(<Text> {item} </Text>)
                 }
              }
        </List>
      </View>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose this is you PDF array list,

```
pdfList = [
    {name: 'Felipe Calderon', year: 2012},
    {name: 'Rocio Calderon Martinez', year: 2012},
    {name: 'Laura Martinez Calderon', year: 2012},
    {name: 'Marcos Alberto Gonzales Calderon', year: 2012}, 
    {name: 'Brenda Calderon Ibañez', year: 2012},   
];
```

you can create a function which sends searchqueries, here example 'Calderon' is your search query.

```
let searchResult = pdfList.filter(({name}) => name.includes('Calderon'));

Console.log(searchResult)
```

now use this search result and update your state data which is used for displaying PDF list in your UI.

Comment: not really following what you mean by update my state data, as doesn't your solution only search for one entry? Instead of filtering based on what the user is inputting? I want it to be a search bar (using <TextInput>) where the user enters text into the search bar and the list of PDF names shown narrow depending on what the user inputted. Your solution hard codes what the names include, but I dont want to do that  because there are so many entries and theyre already stored in my pdf array.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has helped me except this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXgc6ctpEpo&ab_channel=ReactNativeTutorials). I'm going to keep this post up for anyone that hasn't had any luck creating a search filter bar in React Native because that video literally did everything I wanted my pdf list to perfectly.